# Efficient DataTable Group By

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I would like to perform an aggregate query on a DataTable to create another DataTable. I cannot alter the SQL being used to create the initial DataTable.

Original DataTable: (everything is an int)

```
TeamID | MemberID
-------|-----------
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 4
2      | 5
```

Desired result:

```
TeamID | MemberIDCount
-------|--------------
1      | 3
2      | 2
```

If it were SQL I could just do

```
Select TeamID, Count(*) From Table Group By TeamID
```

but in my application, the only way I know how to handle this would be something like this:

```
Dictionary<int,int> d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (d.ContainsKey(dr.ID))
    {
        d[dr.ID] = d[dr.ID] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        d.Add(dr.ID, 1);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may use Linq.

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<int>("TeamID") into grp
               select new
                 {
                 TeamID = grp.Key,
                  MemberCount = grp.Count()
                  };
 foreach (var t in result)
     Console.WriteLine(t.TeamID + " " + t.MemberCount);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public DataTable GroupBy(string i_sGroupByColumn, string i_sAggregateColumn, DataTable i_dSourceTable)
{

    DataView dv = new DataView(i_dSourceTable);

    //getting distinct values for group column
    DataTable dtGroup = dv.ToTable(true, new string[] { i_sGroupByColumn });

    //adding column for the row count
    dtGroup.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

    //looping thru distinct values for the group, counting
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtGroup.Rows) {
        dr["Count"] = i_dSourceTable.Compute("Count(" + i_sAggregateColumn + ")", i_sGroupByColumn + " = '" + dr[i_sGroupByColumn] + "'");
    }

    //returning grouped/counted result
    return dtGroup;
}
```

Example:

```
DataTable desiredResult = GroupBy("TeamID", "MemberID", dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Group By in LINQ**

```
var listInfo = (from infoMember in context.Members
                where infoMember.TeamID  == TeamID 
                group infoMember by new
                { infoMember.TeamID, infoMember.MemberIDCount } into newInfoMemeber
                select new ClassName
                {
                   TeamID = newInfo.Key.TeamID,
                   MemberIDCount = newInfo.Key.MemberIDCOunt,
                   Count = newInfo.Count(),
                   TotalCount = (from infoMemeber2 in context.Members
                                 where infoMemeber2.TeamID== TeamID
                                 select infoResult2).Count()
                }).AsEnumerable();
```