# Amend C# Group By Code to Allow Spaces in Field Names

Tags: c#, winforms

This is with reference to the code provided in this answer: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by/8472044#8472044) by @Tim-Schmelter.

The code is to group a DataTable by a specific column and add a count to the column (pivot):

```
   public DataTable GroupBy(string i_sGroupByColumn, string i_sAggregateColumn, DataTable i_dSourceTable)
    {

        DataView dv = new DataView(i_dSourceTable);

        //getting distinct values for group column
        DataTable dtGroup = dv.ToTable(true, new string[] { i_sGroupByColumn });

        //adding column for the row count
        dtGroup.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        //looping thru distinct values for the group, counting
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtGroup.Rows)
        {
            dr["Count"] = i_dSourceTable.Compute("Count(" + i_sAggregateColumn + ")", i_sGroupByColumn + " = '" + dr[i_sGroupByColumn] + "'");
        }

        //returning grouped/counted result
        return dtGroup;
    }
```

However, my datatable has a column (I can't change this) with a space in the field name, ie: "Solution ID"

When I pass that into the code above, using this:

```
DataTable Solutions = GroupBy("Solution ID", "Solution ID", tbQ);
```

...I get the error: **Syntax error: Missing operand after 'ID' operator.**

I have tried encapsulating with [], amending the space to +, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to amend the code above, to accept a column with a space in it?

Thank you, Mark

Comment: Just to double check, but using `DataTable Solutions = GroupBy("[Solution ID]", "[Solution ID]", tbQ);` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried encapsulating with [], amending the space to +, but it doesn't work.

Well changing the space to `+` certainly won't work, but encapsulating in brackets should.  try

```
if(!i_sAggregateColumn.StartsWith("["))
    i_sAggregateColumn = "[" + i_sAggregateColumn + "]";

if(!i_sGroupByColumn.StartsWith("["))
    i_sGroupByColumn = "[" + i_sGroupByColumn + "]";
```

Note that if your column name already contains brackets [you'll have to try something else](http://forums.asp.net/t/1599984.aspx/1).

Comment: Thank you - I also came up with just renaming the column in the datatable in memory:   Solutions.Columns["Solution ID"].ColumnName = "SolutionID";  Hope this helps too.