# Running SQL Against a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net, datatable

I have pragmatically generated a `DataTable` in ASP.NET 3.5 and now I want to use group by and do some calculations using SQL on this `DataTable`.

My question is: is it possible to write a new SQL query against this `DataTable` and generate a new updated `DataTable`?

For e.g.:

```
select ID, sum(Rate) 
from **dataTable** 
group by ID
```

Comment: No, not really - a `DataTable` is **not** a SQL-capable database - it's just an in-memory data structure....

Comment: Where are you getting the data from for the DataTable?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I have written a function in ASP.NET to query the SQL server and then I've done some calculations on that data and added that data to the DataTable and the function actually returns the DataTable. The place from where I am calling that function is different and I need to do some more calculations on this generated DataTable.

Comment: FYI - can't tell if you know this, but the `DataTable` class has nothing to do with ASP.NET. It is part of ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot  re-write SQL against the `Datatable`, but you can use the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`, `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort` string properties to further filter your current set of data:

Example from **MSDN**:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form {
   protected TextBox Text1;
   protected DataSet DataSet1;

   public static void Main() {
      DemostrateDataView();
   }

   private static void DemostrateDataView() {
      // Create a DataTable with one column
      DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
      DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Col", typeof(int));
      dt.Columns.Add(column); 

      // Add 5 rows on Added state 
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
         row["Col"] = i;
         dt.Rows.Add(row);
      }

      // Add 5 rows on Unchanged state 
      for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
         DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
         row["Col"] = i;
         dt.Rows.Add(row);
         // Calling AcceptChanges will make the DataRowVersion change from Added to Unchanged in this case
         row.AcceptChanges();
      }

      // Create a DataView
      DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

      Console.WriteLine("Print unsorted, unfiltered DataView");
      PrintDataView(dv);

      // Changing the Sort order to descending
      dv.Sort = "Col DESC";

      Console.WriteLine("Print sorted DataView. Sort = 'Col DESC'");
      PrintDataView(dv);

      // Filter by an expression. Filter all rows where column 'Col' have values greater or equal than 3
      dv.RowFilter = "Col < 3";

      Console.WriteLine("Print sorted and Filtered DataView by RowFilter. RowFilter = 'Col > 3'");
      PrintDataView(dv);

      // Removing Sort and RpwFilter to ilustrate RowStateFilter. DataView should contain all 10 rows back in the original order
      dv.Sort = String.Empty;
      dv.RowFilter = String.Empty;

      // Show only Unchanged rows or last 5 rows
      dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Unchanged;

      Console.WriteLine("Print Filtered DataView by RowState. RowStateFilter =  DataViewRowState.Unchanged");
      PrintDataView(dv);
   }

   private static void PrintDataView(DataView dv) {
      // Printing first DataRowView to demo that the row in the first index of the DataView changes depending on sort and filters
      Console.WriteLine("First DataRowView value is '{0}'", dv[0]["Col"]);

      // Printing all DataRowViews 
      foreach (DataRowView drv in dv) {
         Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", drv["Col"]);
      }
   }
}
```

**More info**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

Datatable **Group By**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8472044/752527