# converting VB.Net Linq to C# Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

trying to conver the following VB.net Linq to C# Linq

```
Dim query =
    From row In dt.AsEnumerable
    Group row By G = New With {.Price = row.Field(Of Double?)("price")}.Price,
                  New With {.Cat = row.Field(Of Integer?)("category")}.Cat
                 Into ProductGroups = Group
```

i've tried some websites but none worked as expected.

Comment: _Well_,first of all, Stackoverflow is not **code converter**. However, there are some converting questions in here. IMO it is not welcome. People will probably suggest you third party converters like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @SonerGönül tried every converter i could find, from this one i got  `line 1 col 2: EOF expected`

Comment: @user1590636 - Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8472111/142822

Comment: @SonerGönül While I agree that SO is not a code converter, he had already tried to use a converter and was having issues. Now if anyone else makes the same type of mistake, they have somewhere that can give them some ideas. A question about using code converters (even though it wasn't phrased that way) is just as valid as a question about visual studio IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online converters are not handling this, so this must be frustrating for you.  Try this:

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable
            group row by new {Price = row.Field<double?>("price")}.Price, new {Cat = row.Field<int?>("category")}.Cat into g
            select new {G = g.Key, g};
```

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of C# LINQ to validate the above, but assuming it's correct, it should be an accepted answer instead, cause the other one is not even C#.

Comment: As discussed above, I don't believe SO is a code converter. The link even states "LINQ support is not yet fully reliable. Please post cases that do not work to our feedback forum." His problem was with incorrectly using the converter. If the converter is giving an incorrect output, then the best place to discuss that is in the forum where they can do something to correct it (possibly helping more people with more situations when the problem is corrected)

Comment: and +1 for the conversion. Even though I think the anonymous type would be easier to read as `new { Price = row.Field<double?>("price), Cat = row.Field<int?>("category") }`, yours is a conversion of what is already there.

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer your problem instead of converting it for you. Make sure you use proper syntax in the converters.

Here is what you are looking for to convert:

```
Dim query = _
From row In dt.AsEnumerable _
Group row By G = New With {.Price = row.Field(Of Double?)("price")}.Price, _
              New With {.Cat = row.Field(Of Integer?)("category")}.Cat _
             Into ProductGroups = Group
```

Even though it is not needed in VB2012, it seems like in the converters still use the `_` character to specify that the statement is not complete on that line.

You can use the [link listed in the comments to the question](http://developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp) to convert it now.

Comment: I don't think Double? is allowed in VB.Net either , isn't it System.Nullable(of Decimal) or something like that ?

Comment: I couldn't tell you, since I am not a VB developer. I know that double is base 2 and decimal is base 10. Either way the question supplied the source, correct or incorrect.

Comment: all i know is that the code in the question works as it should in vb.net! its not showing any error

Comment: @user1590636 , then whats wrong? this answer should solve your problem , try a conversion tool , like this http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: but yes the answer solved the problem because the converter works after adding _

Comment: @NickFreeman `_` is not needed in VB2012. It appears that the convertors have not been updated to take that into consideration.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for that. Like I said I am not a VB developer, i just noticed them missing and so I tried them in the converter. I will update my answer.