# C# DataTable: Get most frequent value for every column

Tags: c#, datatable, frequency

I want to get the most frequent value for every column in my DataTable.
I found an answer to a similar question for a Table, but it does not seem to work for my DataTable.

Actually I would welcome a list of distinct values for every column.

Comment: You can use GroupBy on your datatable.

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by