# how to merge rows with similar data

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable with 3 columns ( first name, last name, age), I wanna browse through it and look for the rows that have the same first and last name, and replace them with one row that'll have the same first and last name. As for the age column I wanna put all the ages in one cell and seperate them with a '|' or ';'.

Before:

John  # Doe  # 24

John  # Doe  # 35

After:

John # Doe # 24|35

Comment: to be honest I'm clueless, I thouhgt about converting the datatable into a List. But I'm not sure if it's the best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ and the extensions in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` assembly like [DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) to group the rows and join the values you want like this:

```
        var dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof (int));

        dt.Rows.Add("John", "Doe", 23);
        dt.Rows.Add("John", "Doe", 24);
        dt.Rows.Add("John", "Doe", 25);

        var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     group row by new {A=row.Field<string>("A"), B=row.Field<string>("B")} into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         CustomerName = grp.Key,
                         Items = String.Join(",",grp.Select(r=>r.Field<int>("C")))
                     };
        foreach (var t in result)
            Console.WriteLine(t.CustomerName + " " + t.Items);
```

The trick is to realize that what you ask is how to group the data and then aggregate the value column using something other than Count() or Sum()

You'll find many questions in SO that ask how to group DataTable rows, eg. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by) that you can use as a reference to make more complex groupings