# Parsing table rows into nested collections

Tags: c#

I have a data table like below. I am trying use C# to group them using the nested collection class structure in Listing 2 so that the result is like list 3.  Each collection on each level should not have repeating value.  Does anyone know how to parse the table? Thanks.

Listing 1:

```
    user_ID firstName Role                      service                     facility        RWP      Fac_ID     svc_ID   rol_ID
    ------- --------- -----------------------   --------------------------- --------------  -----
    874     Joe       Tech                      Primary                     New York, NY    9-2       1          1        1 
    874     Joe       Reviewer                  Primary                     New York, NY    2-5       1          1        2
    874     Joe       Reviewer                  Primary                     Los Angeles, CA 2-5       2          1        2
    874     Joe       Super User                Primary                     Los Angeles, CA 9-10      2          1        3
    874     Joe       Administrator             Application Administration  Los Angeles, CA 1-2       2          2        4 
    874     Joe       Super User                Application Administration  Chicago, IL     10-12     3          2        3
```

Listing 2:

```
Facility {
    fac Facility; 
    List<Service> Services;
}
Service{
    svc Service;
    List<Role> Roles;
}
Role{
    rol Role;
    List<RWP> RWP;
}
RWP{
    string H;
}
fac{
    int fac_ID;
    string fac_Name;
}
svc{
    int svc_ID;
    string svc_Name;
}
rol{
    int rol_ID;
    string rol_Name;
}
```

Listing 3:

```
                 NY
                 |  
          +-- Primary --+   
          |             |
       Tech             Reviewer
       |                       |
       9-2                     2-5

       +------- LA --------------------+
       |                               |
    Application                 +----Primary----+   
    Administration              |               |
       |                        |               |
   Administrator              Reviewer      Super User
       |                        |               |
      1-2                      2-5             9-10

              CH
              |
        Application 
        Administration
              |
         Super User
              |
            10-12
```

Listing 4:

```
private static void populateUserFSR(ref User thisUser, DataTable dt, string FSRtype)
{
    string tmpFacility = string.Empty;
    string tmpService = string.Empty;
    string tmpRole = string.Empty;
    FSR thisFSR = new FSR();
    thisFSR.serviceRoles = new List<SR>();

    SR thisSR = new SR();
    thisSR.service = new List<Service>();
    thisSR.rolesWatchProviders = new List<RP>();

    RP thisRWP = new RP();
    thisRWP.providers = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (r["facility_ID"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() != tmpFacility)
        {
            //new facility row
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpFacility))
            {
                //add to a proper collection according to their FSRtype
                switch (FSRtype)
                {
                    case "Assigned":
                        thisUser.FSRAssigned.Add(thisFSR);
                        break;
                    case "Preferred":
                        thisUser.FSRPreferred.Add(thisFSR);
                        break;
                    case "Selected":
                        thisUser.FSRSelected.Add(thisFSR);
                        break;
                }
                thisFSR = new FSR();
                thisFSR.serviceRoles = new List<SR>();

                thisSR = new SR();
                thisSR.service = new List<Service>();
                thisSR.rolesWatchProviders = new List<RP>();

                thisRWP = new RP();
                thisRWP.providers = new List<string>();
            }
            tmpFacility = r["facility_ID"].ToString();
            tmpService = string.Empty;
            tmpRole = string.Empty;
            thisFSR.facility = new Facility();
            thisFSR.facility.Facility_ID = int.Parse(r["facility_ID"].ToString());
            thisFSR.facility.Facility_Name = r["facility_name"].ToString();

            //only rank with FSR Assigned, no ranking with FSR Preferred
            if (FSRtype == "Assigned")
                thisFSR.rank = int.Parse(r["rank"].ToString());
        }

        if (r["Service_ID"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() != tmpService)
        {
            tmpService = r["Service_ID"].ToString();
            tmpRole = string.Empty;
            Service thisService = new Service();
            thisService.ServiceID = int.Parse(r["Service_ID"].ToString());
            thisService.ServiceName = r["fac_service"].ToString();
            thisSR.service = new List<Service>();
            thisSR.service.Add(thisService);
            thisFSR.serviceRoles.Add(thisSR);
        }

        if (r["Role"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() != tmpRole)
        {
            tmpRole = r["Role"].ToString();
            thisRWP.role = new Role();
            thisRWP.role.Id = int.Parse(r["role_ID"].ToString());
            thisRWP.role.Role = r["Role"].ToString();
            thisRWP.providers = getCohortPCP(thisUser);
            thisSR.rolesWatchProviders.Add(thisRWP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you have so far so we have something to start with?

Comment: added my code in listing4.  The end result is having 6 identical copies of the collection.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by) question? Sounds a lot like yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list3 = list1.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("facility"))
                 .Select(g=> new Facility{ Facility=g.Key,       
                             Services = g.GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Role"))
                                         .Select(g1=> new Service{
                                                    Service = g1.Key,
                                                    Roles = g1.GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("RWP"))
                                                              .Select(g2=> new Role{
                                                                  H = g2.Key
                                                               }).ToList()
                                                 }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: @user266909 ah, I thought you have `lis1` is normal `List`, if it's a `DataTable`, you have to use `AsEnumerable` to start using `LINQ` on it, see my update.

Comment: Now I need to make each string key field in Facility.facility, Service.service, and Role.role to be object as modified in my Listing 2. An alternative is to add an Id of int after each string key. How do i do that?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user266909 it's unclear what `fac, svc, rol` are, you should show the definition of them, the original definitions are OK, I think you want to append something to some field but it's not very clear to me, you should explain more about that, such as by example of the input and the desired output.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I added the properties of fac, svc, rol in the Listing 2

Comment: @user266909 where can you pull the data for `fac_ID, svc_ID, rol_ID` to create the `fac, svc, rol` objects?

Comment: No idea whats happening, but +1 for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is very simple:

1. Create dictionary of RWPs - `Dictionary<string, RWP>` (name it rwps):

   ```
   // foreach row in datatable
   string strRWP = row["RWP"];
   if (!rwps.ContainsKey(strRWP))
       rwps[strRWP] = new RWP(strRWP);
   ```
2. Create and fill `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RWP>>` = dictionary of {role name to set of RWP}. Just foreach rows and fill this dictionary (name it dicRoles):

   ```
   // foreach row in datatable
   string strRole = row["Role"], strRWP = row["RWP"];

   if (!dicRoles.ContainsKey(strRole))
       dicRoles[strRole] = new Dictionary<string, RWP>();

   if (!dicRoles[strRole].ContainsKey(strRWP))
       dicRoles[strRole][strRWP] = rwps[strRWP];
   ```
3. Create `Dictionary<string, Role> roles` from `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RWP>> dicRoles`:

   ```
   foreach (var pair in dicRoles)
       roles[pair.Key] = new Role(pair.Key, pair.Value.Values.ToList();
   ```
4. Then create and fill `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Role>>` dicServices.

   ```
   // foreach row in datatable
   string strService = row["Service"], strRole = row["Role"];

   if (!dicServices.ContainsKey(strService))
       dicServices[strService] = new Dictionary<string, Role>();

   if (!dicServices[strService].ContrainsKey(strRole))
       dicServices[strService][strRole] = roles[strRole];
   ```
5. Repeat step 3 to create services from dicServices.
6. Repeat step 3-4 to create facilities

Remember, this isn't optimal code. I just tried to explain my idea much easier.

Comment: Is it possible to use nested List<> as I have?

Comment: what you mean by nested List<>? `new Role(pair.Key, pair.Value.Values.ToList();` means that in constructor of `Role` `pair.Key` will be assigned to field `string Role` and `pair.Value.Values.ToList()` (which of type List<RWP>) will be assigned to `List<RWP> RWP`. All objects (of types RWP, Role, Service and Facility) are unique and are used once.

Comment: King King's answer does the same but only uses Linq to get result. Use his method because it's shorter (and faster). I just tried to explain the idea of getting result not to give you "nice" implementation :)