# How do I use SELECT GROUP BY in DataTable.Select(Expression)?

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates

I try to remove the duplicate rows by select a first row from every group.
For Example

```
PK     Col1     Col2
1        A        B
2        A        B
3        C        C
4        C        C
```

I want a return:

```
PK     Col1     Col2
1        A        B
3        C        C
```

I tried following code but it didn't work:

```
DataTable dt = GetSampleDataTable(); //Get the table above.
dt = dt.Select("SELECT MIN(PK), Col1, Col2 GROUP BY Col1, Col2);
```

Comment: You can't.  Use LINQ instead.

Comment: You must not group by the PK field...

Comment: I would like to use whatever, but I want to return a DataTable object.

Comment: Why not delegate grouping or other complex processing to sql at database level which would be more natural place

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient DataTable Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`DataTable`'s `Select` method only supports simple filtering expressions like `{field} = {value}`.  It does not support complex expressions, let alone SQL/Linq statements.

You can, however, use Linq extension methods to extract a collection of `DataRow`s then create a *new* `DataTable`.

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new {Col1 = r["Col1"], Col2 = r["Col2"]})
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["PK"]).First())
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What assembly reference do you need to use in order to get this to work. I am using System.data but the GroupBy command is stating I am missing an assembly reference.

Comment: What extension is this .CopyToDataTable() ?

Comment: @SebastianWidz [`System.Data.DataSetExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user5013 [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the System.Linq namespace.  You need a reference to `System.Core` if you don't have one already.

Comment: How to use having clause in this?

Comment: If you mean the equivalent of a SQL "HAVING", that gets applied to the _groups_, so you would add a `Where` call after the `GroupBy` that filters the groups (e.g. by count, or sum, or something else)

Answer (score 8):

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID")).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What extension is this .CopyToDataTable() ?

Answer (score 7):

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["Col1"], Col2 = r["Col2"] })
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();

        row["PK"] = g.Min(r => r.Field<int>("PK"));
        row["Col1"] = g.Key.Col1;
        row["Col2"] = g.Key.Col2;

        return row;

    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution sort by Col1 and group by Col2. Then extract value of Col2 and display it in a mbox.

```
var grouped = from DataRow dr in dt.Rows orderby dr["Col1"] group dr by dr["Col2"];
string x = "";
foreach (var k in grouped) x += (string)(k.ElementAt(0)["Col2"]) + Environment.NewLine;
MessageBox.Show(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on @Alfred Wallace's solution :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Col2");

        dt.Rows.Add("120", "34");
        dt.Rows.Add("121", "34");
        dt.Rows.Add("122", "34");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "345");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "345");
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "345");

        var grouped = from DataRow dr in dt.Rows orderby dr["Col1"] group dr by dr["Col2"];
        string xxx = "", yyy = "";
        foreach (var k_group in grouped)
        {                
            xxx += (string)(k_group.ElementAt(0)["Col1"]) + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (DataRow item_dr in k_group)
            {                    
                yyy += (string)(item_dr["Col1"]) + Environment.NewLine;
                //  or use WhatEverMethod(item_dr);
            }
            var zzz = k_group.Max(g => g["Col1"]);
            var qqq = k_group.Key;
        }
```