# C# How do i merge two DataTable Row into one row

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have a datatable that looks like below which have been populated from Database

[image]

How can i make the result to look like below

[image]

Sorry for my bad explanation,Thank you very much

Comment: Do a GROUP BY..

Comment: The thing is , this datatable i have manually insert row from another datatable, is there anyway to use C# to di it?

Comment: @KuHan I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040600/5519709) for C#, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with Datatable instead of SQL you can use:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new {PN = r["PN"], Description = r["Description"]})
       .Select(g => 
       {  
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            row["PN"] =  g.Key.PN;
            row["Description"] = g.Key.Description;
            row["January"] =  g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("January"));
            row["February"] =  g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("February"));
            row["March"] =  g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("March"));
            row["April"] =  g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("April"));
            
            return row;
       
       })
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

See: [How do I use SELECT GROUP BY in DataTable.Select(Expression)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407387/how-do-i-use-select-group-by-in-datatable-selectexpression)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write something like this:

```
Select
PN,
[Description],
Sum(January) AS January,
Sum(February) AS February,
Sum(March) AS March,
Sum(April) AS April
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY
PN,
[Description]
```

Comment: The thing is , this datatable i have manually insert row from another datatable, is there anyway to use C# to di it?