# Group by its count from datatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am new to linq.

I have a datatable and need to update a column according to another column using linq.

My value

```
customer | value1  |  value2  | count
---------------------------------------- 
   A     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
   A     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
   C     |   sda   |  sdas    |  0
```

Expected Value

```
customer | value1  |  value2  | count
---------------------------------------- 
   A     |   sda   |  sdas    |  2
   A     |   sda   |  sdas    |  2
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  3
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  3
   B     |   sda   |  sdas    |  3
   C     |   sda   |  sdas    |  1
```

Could you please suggest me the required linq for the above datatable?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please, show us your code and explain where did you get stuck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: `I have a datatable and need to update a column according to another column using linq` how is this `DataTable` being filled, is it bound to a source? Could you please update your post to include what you've tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide your code but I think you are looking for a something like this:(Assuming your DataTable is called 'dt')

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // loop whole table
{
   //Find count of rows which has same value
    var count = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(i=> i["customer"] == dr["customer"] && i["value1"] == dr["value1"] && i["value2"] == dr["value2"]).Count();
    
    /Then update count column
    dr["count"] = count;
}
```

Another approach you can follow is that `GroupBy` multiple columns in datatable.

```
 dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(g => new {Customer = g["customer"], Value1 = g["value1"], Value2= g["value2"]})
    .Select(g=> 
    {
        var newRow = dtNew.NewRow();
        
        row["customer"] = g.Key.Customer;
        row["value1"] = g.Key.Value1;
        row["value2"] = g.Key.Value2;
        row["count"] = g.Count();
        
        return newRow;
    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

See: [How do I use SELECT GROUP BY in DataTable.Select(Expression)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407387/how-do-i-use-select-group-by-in-datatable-selectexpression)