# Re-arrange rows of Datatable in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have multiple rows in a datatable, see a sample below:

### Existing Table

```
Name        Date         Value        Type

ABC(I)         11/11/2013   12.36      I
DEF(I)         11/11/2013   1          I
GHI(I)          -do-        -do-       I
JKL(P)                                 P
MNO(P)                                 P
PQR(D)                                 D
STU(D)          -d0-        -do-       D
```

### Required Table

```
Name        Date         Value        Type

JKL(P)                                 P
MNO(P)                                 P
PQR(D)                                 D
STU(D)          -d0-        -do-       D
ABC(I)         11/11/2013   12.36      I
DEF(I)         11/11/2013   1          I
GHI(I)          -do-        -do-       I
```

### COndition to use

Sorting should be as per the column Type. Now I need a small change in order of the rows to be shown in the gridview. That is rows of Payment will come first then all Dues and at last all Interests types will come.

### What I tried:

1. Sorting of column but it was not what I need.
2. Custom Grouping suggested by Tim Schmelter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by/)

Code was:

```
public DataTable GroupBy(string i_sGroupByColumn, string i_sAggregateColumn, DataTable i_dSourceTable)
{

    DataView dv = new DataView(i_dSourceTable);

    //getting distinct values for group column
    DataTable dtGroup = dv.ToTable(true, new string[] { i_sGroupByColumn });

    //adding column for the row count
    dtGroup.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

    //looping thru distinct values for the group, counting
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtGroup.Rows) {
        dr["Count"] = i_dSourceTable.Compute("Count(" + i_sAggregateColumn + ")", i_sGroupByColumn + " = '" + dr[i_sGroupByColumn] + "'");
    }

    //returning grouped/counted result
    return dtGroup;
}
```

I dont know where and what I am lacking/missing. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

try linq to order your table:

```
var query = dtGroup.AsEnumerable()
           .OrderBy(c=> c.Field<DateTime?>("Date"))
           .ThenByDescending(c=> c.Field<string>("Name"));
DataView dv2   = query.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want first sorting on P, D, I and then on date

```
    Dictionary<string, int> sortDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    sortDictionary.Add("P", 1);
    sortDictionary.Add("D", 2);
    sortDictionary.Add("I", 3);


    var q = from row in dtGroup.AsEnumerable()
            let type = sortDictionary[row.Field<string>("Name").Substring(4, 1)]
            orderby type, row.Field<string>("Name")
            select row;

    foreach (var r in q)
    {
        string x = r["Name"].ToString() + r["Date"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: OK, you can change the orderby by changing the row.Field<DateTime?>("Date") to row.Field<string>("Name"). var q is the datatable you're looking for