# LINQ Dynamic List

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have classes:

```
Public Class Data

    Public Property ColumnList As List(Of Column)
    Public Property RowList As List(Of Row)
End Class

Public Class Row

    Public Property CellList As List(Of Cell)
End Class

Public Class Column

    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Cell

    Public Property value As Object
    Public Property col As Column
End Class
```

Then I want to check if a List of columnnames would be a Primary Key (like in SQL) for the data, e.g.

```
ColumnFieldNames = {"FieldA", "FieldB"}
```

`ColumnList` contains 3 `Column`s named `FieldA`, `FieldB`, `FieldC`.
`RowList` contains 3 `CellList`s each filled with values for `FieldA`, `FieldB`, `FieldC` and a reference to the `Column`.

```
Data.ColumnList(0).name = "FieldA" 
Data.ColumnList(1).name = "FieldB"
data.RowList(0).CellList(0).value = 1
data.RowList(0).CellList(0).column = ColumnList(0)
data.RowList(0).CellList(1).value = 2
data.RowList(0).CellList(1).column = ColumnList(1)
data.RowList(1).CellList(0).value = 34
data.RowList(1).CellList(0).column = ColumnList(0)
data.RowList(1).CellList(1).value = 2
data.RowList(1).CellList(1).column = ColumnList(1)
```

etc.

I'd like some kind of `group by ... having count(*) > 1`
or `select count(1)` - Statement so if I would choose `FieldB` as `ColumnFieldNames` it would return something, as there are more than one row containing `CellList.value = 2`. If I would choose {"FieldA", "FieldB"} as `ColumnFieldNames` it would return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it the main objective is to check if a set of fields may represent a primary key on your data structure. In other words, if a set of fields may uniquely identify a row.

As FloatingKiwi pointed out, you'd better use the `DataTable` class. It provides you with a number of handy utilities to store and manipulate with your data. And your question may be answered by this simple code:

```
Private Function IsPK_DataTable(data As DataTable, ParamArray fields As String()) As Boolean
    Return New DataView(data).ToTable(True, fields).Rows.Count = data.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Here the data is first wrapped with a `DataView` object which allows us to pick up only selected columns from our data table (with `ToTable(..., fields)`) and only rows which are unique for these selected columns (by passing `True` as the first parameter to `ToTable()`). Now, if the resultign row count matches the initial one, the passed field set may be primary key on our data.

The full demo code can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fhMgv

---

If you still inclined to use your custom data structure representation, the respective primary key check function may look like this:

```
Private Function IsPK_CustomData(data As Data, ParamArray fields As String()) As Boolean
    Dim keyValues = data.RowList _
        .[Select](Function(r) r.CellList.Where(Function(c) fields.Contains(c.col.name)) _
        .[Select](Function(c) c.value).ToArray()).ToArray()
    For i As Integer = 1 To keyValues.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If keyValues(i).SequenceEqual(keyValues(j)) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Full demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RDl5Nl

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reinventing the wheel here. The DataTable class can handle your class structure already and supports sql like filter expressions. For the grouping try checking out the following post:
[Efficient DataTable Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by)

Comment: The old wheel was too round.